# Passing parameters to external Qt Script

Tags: qt, parameters, scripting

I'm new to Qt Script. I have a working "placeholder" script that takes no arguments and is called from the Qt application. Now I want to add parameters, specifically a QBitArray (or some representation of its contents) and some integers. Does anyone know how to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316218/qt-script-function-wrapping) deals with wrapping a native function with a script, so that the native function can be called (with arguments). But I am doing the reverse - call an external script from the Qt application and supply parameters.

I've read the [official docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtscript-index.html), which also talk about function wrapping, but unless I am missing something I only see it discuss my use case for scripts with no arguments.

Does anyone know how to pass parameters from a Qt application to an external Qt Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out. 
There is some code in the [QScriptValue::call()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscriptvalue.html) documentation that shows how it is done. I honestly have no idea why it works, but that is ok for now.
The first half of that code shows how to use scripts set to QScriptValues and call one QScriptValue with another as a parameter.

The second part shows how to pass arguments in general. This is simpler. Here's a copy/past of the relevant bits:

```
QScriptEngine engine;
QScriptValue global = engine.globalObject();
engine.evaluate("function cube(x) { return x * x * x; }");
QScriptValue cube = global.property("cube");
QScriptValueList args;
args << 3;
qDebug() << cube.call(QScriptValue(), args).toNumber(); // 27
```

Now, QScripts don't need formal parameters. You can pass a variable number of arguments, for example by repeating args << in a loop, and use the special arguments[] property to refer to them, like this:

```
function foo()
{
  return arguments[0] + arguments[1];
}
```